# UTF-8 character counting false

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

I have received my letters UTF-8 text. but jquery length() false count şğıçöü.

```
var $text= "<p>ğ</p>";
        var $regexTM = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
        var $trimtagTM = $text.replace($regexTM,""); 
        var $completeTM = $trimtagTM.replace("&nbsp;", "");

        alert($completeTM.length);
        // call back = 9
```

What do I do after I could not find it here

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Make sure you specify correct charset for your script into whatever facility you use it. I suppose it is browser, so add it to `<script>` tag.